# Can you kindly explain me about this compiler warning in java?

Tags: java, markov-chains

The compiler warning that I get is:

```
Markov.java:40: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addElement(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.Vector
    suf.addElement(word);
```

This is the code:

```
   void add(String word)
   {
        Vector suf = (Vector) statetab.get(prefix);
        if (suf == null) {
        suf = new Vector();
        statetab.put(new Prefix(prefix), suf);
    }
    suf.addElement(word);
    prefix.pref.removeElementAt(0);
    prefix.pref.addElement(word);  // same error here
```

I am new to Java and I am trying to run the code from The Practice of Programming by Brian W. Kernighan and Rob Pike.

Comment: This has to do with your use of generics. Here's a [nice tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). Specifically, you'll want to look at [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Answer (score 2):

A `Vector` is a collection type that can declare using "generics" what type of element it contains. In fact, it is strongly preferred that you do declare what's inside it, and that's why you get the warning.

You declare what type is inside the collection using angle brackets (`<Type>`). In your case, the `Vector` contains Strings, so it becomes `Vector<String>`

```
Hashtable<Prefix,Vector<String>> statetab; // proper type for statetab

void add(String word)
{
    Vector<String> suf = statetab.get(prefix);
    if (suf == null) {
        suf = new Vector<String>();
        statetab.put(new Prefix(prefix), suf);
    }
    suf.addElement(word);
    prefix.pref.removeElementAt(0);
    prefix.pref.addElement(word);  // same error here
```

You can fix your code like the above - however you didn't show where you declared `statetab` so I made a guess at how you should change its type.

You should probablty also change the field `pref` inside the `Prefix` class and make it a `Vector<String>` as well.

Comment: Oh. Statetab is a Hashtable. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Oh my. Thanks for your help, Erwin. I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The warning is because you are using [*raw types*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) because you used a *generic class or interface without any type arguments*. You could specify the type with something like

```
Vector<String> suf = (Vector<String>) statetab.get(prefix);
```

Also, I suggest you move to the slightly more modern [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Also, if you fix the generic on `statetab` then you shouldn't need to cast.

Comment: I can vote because of low repu but I appreciate your help. Thanks :)